# What's the use of "-なきゃ"?

Tags: grammar

I have seen two example of this.

The first example come from "恋する星座" part 9 where the girl said a sentences with words "行かなきゃ"

The second example come from the song "Catch A Break" sung by Eguchi Takuya. The lyrics goes "買いに行かなきゃ"

Why does they use "-なきゃ" in said examples? Is it used only in daily conversation? What are the other example of words using "-なきゃ"?

[Sorry if I ask too much I'm really curious]

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61427/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24353/9831 / 
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60701/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4213/9831

Answer (score 4):

-なきゃ is a common casual contraction (amongst a few other variations) for the form -なければいけません, which literally means “it is no good if the action is not done”, aka. showing obligation that the action *must* be performed.

from your example:

- 行かなきゃ: must go
- 買いに行かなきゃ: must go to buy

---

FYI, here are some other variations and contractions of the structure

Formal

- なければいけません
- なくてはいけません
- なければなりません
- なくてはなりません
- ないといけません

Casual

- なきゃ(いけません)
- なくちゃ(いけません)
- なきゃ(なりません)
- なくちゃ(なりません)

source: my experience and my Japanese class notes

Comment: Strictly speaking, なきゃ is a contraction of なければ, not なければいけません. As you pointed out, いけない does not necessarily follow なきゃ. For example, ～しなきゃだめ.